# solving 3 simultaneous equaitons

Tags: curves

I have 3 equations

$y_1=ax_1^2+bx_1+c$,

$y_2=ax_2^2+bx_2+c$,

$y_3=ax_3^2+bx_3+c$

i.e. 3 pairs of values $x_1$,$y_1$, $x_2$,$y_2$ and $x_3$,$y_3$ and I need to fit the curve. I found lots of code for $n$ pairs using matrices but really just have this simple case of 3

I need $a,b,c$ in terms of the paired values.

There must be a simple equation?

Comment: What you have is a system of *linear* equations on $a$, $b$, $c$. Just solve it using elimination or any other technique you know.

Comment: I understand I have to solve the 3 linear simultanous equations but I dont know how to do that.  I need a,b and c in terms of x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 so I can do for generic data (in a mobile phone automatically)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial.

Comment: So you are trying to get us to help you cheat on a test?

Comment: not trying to cheat on a test.  i have a temperature sensor based on a mobile phone which needs calibrating with 3 values of temp and rms_voltage because the actual curve is a nice polynomial. i'm too old for tests ;)

Comment: You could try Cramer's Rule.

Comment: Thanks lhf - i used lagrange

Comment: r1=1.0
r2=2.0
r3=3.0
t1=1.0
t2=8.0
t3=27.0

d1=(r1-r2)*(r1-r3)
d2=(r2-r1)*(r2-r3)
d3=(r3-r1)*(r3-r2)

a=t1/d1+t2/d2+t3/d3
b=t1*(-x2-x3)/d1 + t2*(-x1-x3)/d2 + t3*(-x1-x2)/d3
c=t1*(-x2*(-x3))/d1 + t2*(-x1*(-x3))/d2 + t3*(-x1*(-x2))/d3

print,a
print,b
print,c

is the answer if i did my algebra right!

Answer (score 0):

If this is just what you need, eliminate variables one after each other. You will be left with one linear equation to solve for $c$ $$c=\frac{x_3 (y_1-y_2)+x_1 (y_2-y_3)+x_2 (y_3-y_1)}{(x_1-x_2) (x_1-x_3)
   (x_2-x_3)}$$ $$b=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}-c (x_1+x_2)$$ $$a=y_1-bx_1-c x_1^2$$